# How to create a Typescript interface for a React prop that access indexes from another component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to define an `items` prop on the Expenses.tsx that will be passed to App.tsx to render a list of expenses, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to structure it so it doesn't give me any errors. I've tried everything from 'object' to 'Array<string | number | Date>' but nothing works, aside from 'any' of course.

Expenses.tsx

```
interface ItemsType {
  items: any;
}

export default function Expenses({ items }: ItemsType) {
  return (
    <Card className="expenses">
      <ExpenseItem
        id={items[0].id}
        title={items[0].title}
        amount={items[0].amount}
        date={items[0].date}
      />
      <ExpenseItem
        id={items[1].id}
        title={items[1].title}
        amount={items[1].amount}
        date={items[1].date}
      />
      <ExpenseItem
        id={items[2].id}
        title={items[2].title}
        amount={items[2].amount}
        date={items[2].date}
      />
      <ExpenseItem
        id={items[3].id}
        title={items[3].title}
        amount={items[3].amount}
        date={items[3].date}
      />
    </Card>
  );
}
```

App.tsx

```
interface Expenses {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  amount: number;
  date: Date;
}

export default function App() {
    const expenses: Expenses[] = [
      {
        id: `e1`,
        title: `Toilet Paper`,
        amount: 94.12,
        date: new Date(2020, 7, 14)
      },
      {
        id: `e2`,
        title: `New TV`,
        amount: 799.49,
        date: new Date(2021, 2, 12)
      },
      {
        id: `e3`,
        title: `Car Insurance`,
        amount: 294.67,
        date: new Date(2021, 2, 28)
      },
      {
        id: `e4`,
        title: `New Desk (Wooden)`,
        amount: 450,
        date: new Date(2021, 5, 12)
      }
    ];

    function addExpenseHandler(expense: Array<object>) {
      console.log(`In App.js`);
      console.log(expenses);
    }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <NewExpense onAddExpense={addExpenseHandler} />
      <Expenses items={expenses} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Click [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-sx16ue?file=components/Expenses/Expenses.tsx) for the whole project

Comment: The type of items is clearly { id: string, title: string, amount: number, date: date}[] etc. You already define it in your component, you named the props `Title`, so export that and set items to `items: Title[]`

Answer (score 1):

Yuji 'Tomita' Tomita answered:

The type of items is clearly { id: string, title: string, amount: number, date: date}[] etc. You already define it in your component, you named the props Title, so export that and set items to items: Title[]